# What does the parameter size mean in Github Repo information

Tags: github-api

I am using Github API to fetch the repo information. In that there is a parameter 'size', its not written in github api documentation what it exactly means. Is it the size of lines of code committed to the repository in bytes?

Here you can see the size parameter in the response returned
http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Comment: possible size in Bytes, the repo it refers to say 0,013kB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering the commands are for a full repo (list, get, edit, ...), it should reference the full size of the elements in that repo, as mentioned in "[**See the size of a github repo before cloning it?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679592/6309)".

It seems to be **in Kb**:

- for small repos like the [example repo "HelloWorld"](https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World): `"size": 140,`: once I clone it, it register on my hard-drive slightly under 140 Kb,
- and for larger repos (like the [git repo](https://api.github.com/repos/git/git) itself, more than 40Mo: `"size": 40844,`).

---

Update (February 2013, from [nulltoken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335418/nulltoken)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090214/what-does-the-parameter-size-mean-in-github-repo-information/14090905#comment20574555_14090905))

The answer "[See the size of a github repo before cloning it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679592/6309)" confirms that the size is in Kb for [git alternates objects](http://git-blame.blogspot.fr/2012/08/bringing-bit-more-sanity-to-alternates.html).

> The disk usage against the bare repository doesn't account for the shared object store and thus returns an "incomplete" value through the API call.

Comment: That's what I thought bu that doesn't seem to be the case. I had cloned a repo django-allauth and the size it shows for it is only 140, whereas there is my own repo in which I have pushed C and C++ codes in that repo the size  comes to around 4000 whereas the former should not be having such a small size

Comment: It think your answer is right, I had mistaken in the size of the two repositories. Most probably the size is in kb

Comment: @Sachin ok. Still a confirmation from GitHub support would be nice.

Comment: See update to this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8679592/335418)** for more information about the way the size is calculated and some potential caveats.

Comment: @nulltoken thank you, and +1 to your answer ;) I have included your comment and referenced your answer in mine, for more visibility.

Comment: I can't believe they would just leave this unspecified. The docs only say "The size of the repository. Size is calculated hourly. When a repository is initially created, the size is 0."

Comment: @JuliusNaeumann True, I only see that parameter explained more with [Repo content](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content), but not for repo information.