# How to update/shrink the size of my github repo after running BFG Repo Cleaner

Tags: git, github, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have cleaned my repo with [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) using the following [procedure](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage):

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-biggest-blobs 500 some-big-repo.git
$ cd some-big-repo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
$ git push
```

I can see that my local repo has shrunk with 1GB. Great. The problem that I'm having now and that I haven't been able to find any info on is that now I would like to also shrink the size of the GitHub-repo as well. How to achieve this?

`git push` didn't work and I also tried `git push origin --force --all` which gave me this error message: `error: --all and --mirror are incompatible`

Answer (score 11):

My advice: don't worry too much about what GitHub reports as the repo size. For various reasons it won't accurately reflect the 'true' size of the repo.

What you *really* care about is the answer to this question:

### How big is this repo on my disk if I do a fresh clone of it from GitHub?

The amount of data you have to download to do a fresh clone of your repo, and the amount of space it takes up on your disk, are the things you really care about (and nearly identical quantities). Try doing a fresh clone and seeing how much data gets transferred and how much room it takes up on your disk. It should match the size of your shrunken repo.

The number reported in the GitHub console (ie at https://github.com/settings/repositories, or in the GitHub API) is not really important to you, which is fortunate, because it enjoys a liberated and somewhat drunken relationship with the more important figure above, due to the use of [Git Alternates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679592/438886), and `git gc` occurring only periodically on GitHub servers.

*Side note: Bitbucket can also [take time](https://twitter.com/Bitbucket/status/884481318196723714) to update reported repo size.*

Just because you ran `git gc` locally on your repo, [doesn't mean GitHub have run it](https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/387926738161774592) on *their* copy of your repo yet, and so their copy of your repo will appear much bigger for a while, even though when you clone it, only the 'essential' information is sent, and so you receive the smaller repo that you desire.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: RobertoTyley what about pushing?

Comment: @little-ancient-forest-kami I'll need a little more context about your question (PussInBoots /was/ able to successfully push, tho his question might make it seem that he wasn't). If you post a new question I'll be happy to answer it if I can.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood this answer but does this give a solution to updating the repository size on GitHub?

Comment: It seems, the same with [Bitbucket.org](http://www.bitbucket.org). After [...] push of 2.8GB files, we did a BFG cleanup, successfully completed `git push` and fresh clone now takes only 266MB. But Bitbucket still reports it as 2.8GB.

Comment: @ArnisJuraga I'm also a bitbucket git repo user. My actual file size in total is 1GB but the repo size is almost 2GB. Overall total is 3GB. Then, I realize is that hidden .git folder and check the objects folder under .git folder and the size is over 2GB! I assumed this is where stored all commit infos.

I was still thinking if it safer to use BFG to clean and remove old commit histories or still okay to delete the whole as is.

Comment: This really seems like a non-answer. If you can't push the mirrored clone, then there is no purpose to using the tool.

Comment: Perfect answer!  I shrunk a clone of my Github repo locally from 455 Mb to 54Mb and pushed it to Gihub. After pushing, the one on Github actually increased in size. I was very worried for a while that I had messed up my Github repo. I just needed to go to sleep and in the morning, Github had updated its copy and a new clone was done to 54Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Push without the `--all` flag, that is, do

```
git push origin --force
```

and that should take care of it.

**EDIT**: Improvising upon discussion in comments

- You can create a new repo on github,
- push to it

  ```
  cd repo_directory
  git remote add new_origin url/to/new/repo
  git push new_origin --mirror
  ```
- if things work out (no errors)

  - rename the github repos (the original to a dummy name and the new one to original)
- Drop the remote `new_origin`. Since the github repo url should be same after you have renamed stuff, the original entry for `[origin]` in `.git/config` should hold good, and you only need remove the new remote added.

  ```
  git remote rm new_origin
  ```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I already tried that command and that it gave me: Everything up-to-date. If I look at the repo size on github.com it still says the repo is over 1 GB. So this command doesn't work either unfortunatelly.

Comment: @PussInBoots In that case, is creating a fresh repo on github and pushing to it, and renaming it later an option?

Comment: @PussInBoots Also, can you update the question with the complete error message you get?

Comment: Are you referring to the same thing VonC pointed out? Btw, that is the entire error message.

Comment: @PussInBoots Yeah, I am referring to the same thing, though I would have first tried to create a new repo and push to it, and if things work out, than rename them (because what is the point of renaming if the pushes don't succeed later on)

Comment: Not finnished testing mate. Will update this thread when I am satisfied. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible:

- rename your current GitHub repo
- create a new one with the same name
- push again to your empty GitHub repo (`git push --mirror`)
- check if the size warning persists in said new GitHub rpeo

Comment: By renaming my repo (which I btw don't want to mess with more than necessary) won't I mess things up?

Comment: @PussInBoots no, the idea is to keep the original repo around, in case you don't like the new one.

Comment: @PussInBoots of course, you always can create a new empty repo, and push to that one new repo (without renaming the other one first), just to see if the size is better.