# Dumping binaries in Git and reverting?

Tags: git, binaryfiles, git-rewrite-history

Assume that I add a 1 GB movie in a git repository commit and push. Next I revert the commit that I just pushed and push that. Now latest head no longer contains the 1 GB file.

Even though I just reverted the commit is it correct that the 1 GB file is now permanently part of the git history? Meaning that even though I am working on the latest head without the 1 GB file the repo is still 1 GB larger and will remain that forever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even though I just reverted the commit is it correct that the 1 GB file is now permanently part of the git history?

Yes, the repo will remain big: a version control system is made to *retain* history.

You would need to filter its history and clean it (with [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) or [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)) in order to reduce its size (and that would change its history)

Plus, as mentioned in "[How to update/shrink the size of my github repo after running BFG Repo Cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25459123/6309)", you would need after the filter:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a restriction on a git repo so its not possible to commit/push *.zip, *.dll files? Besides using .gitignore

Comment: @u123 you can put in place a pre-receive hook which will filter the list of files being pushed (as bit like in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2569960/6309)