# view size of a git repo (bitbucket) before cloning it

Tags: git, bitbucket

this thread is relevant but this is for Github: [See the size of a github repo before cloning it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/see-the-size-of-a-github-repo-before-cloning-it)

Comment: You can see the size in repo settings if you have admin privileges for the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to get this info from the admin panel. However, if you are not an admin, and you're using Bitbucket Cloud, then you can still query the API for it: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D

Comment: =/ "Access denied. You must have write or admin access."

Answer (score 3):

In Bitbucket Cloud, a repository admin can see the size under "Repository Details" under Settings.

In Bitbucket Server too, you can view it under Settings > Repository Details after clicking on "Retrieve Size Details".

Comment: got no settings

Comment: If you are owner, you are able to see it. Check if you are owner or you have admin permisions. Then, as I have said:
1. Enter into the repository
2. Click settings (in the left menu)
3. See repository details after clicking on "Retrieve Size Details".