# How do i see the extension's filesize in visual studo code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I am about to download a VisualStudio Code extension, i want to check the downloads filesize. Sometimes when I am in a rural area, and am on a slow connection... downloading a large file can bring other network processes to their knees.

Is there a way to toggle visual studio code to show/preview each extensions download size?

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  Fortunately despite being on a rural exchange myself I've never had to worry that much about bandwidth.  Aside, I don't know of a direct way within the VS Code Extension explorer but given that most extensions seems to be hosted on github or the like you could always visit the repo first and establish size through that?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/how-can-i-see-the-size-of-a-github-repository-before-cloning-it#:%7E:text=If%20you%20own%20the%20repository,displayed%20next%20to%20its%20designation.) has a few solutions