# Can you grep through an uncloned GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

Based somewhat on:

[How can I see the size of a GitHub repository before cloning it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/how-can-i-see-the-size-of-a-github-repository-before-cloning-it)

Due to poor connectivity does GitHub offer an API to run string function utils (e.g. grep, awk) to grep for specific modules?

Comment: There is the search box in the web UI, but it's not as powerful as a regexp search. There is also [an API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search) for searching, but it looks similarly limited.

Comment: Your question seems to be specific to GitHub; you're not asking about git repos stored outside of GitHub. I've edited your question and added the "github" tag. If that wasn't what you meant, please update.