# How to know the size of a remote repo from http://cgit.freedesktop.org/ before cloning?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

How can i know the size of a remote repo in bash from http://cgit.freedesktop.org/ before to cloning, to be specific this repo :

http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/mesa/mesa.git

Comment: not sure if this is relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646517/see-the-size-of-a-github-repo-before-cloning-it

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer, i tried this but with http://cgit.freedesktop.org does not works :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2884103

Comment: mmm i try to get the size before cloning it, because of this it does not works